# How to set body to get volley request?

Tags: java, android, http, android-volley

Good day, I have a problem with set body to `Request.Method.GET` in Android Volley, my code is like below:

```
public void getRideItem(String userToken) {

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

    String sendRequest;
    JSONObject requestBody = new JSONObject();
    try {
        requestBody.put("lat", "-64.9631");
        requestBody.put("lng", "40.719296");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sendRequest = requestBody.toString();

    String mURL = "https://taxiapp.webfumeprojects.online/api/ride/getHome";

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, mURL,
            null,
            response -> {
                Log.i(TAG, "Mahdi: HomeFragment: getCar: res 0 " + response);
            }, error -> {
        error.printStackTrace();
    }) {
        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() {

            byte[] body = new byte[0];
            try {
                body = sendRequest.getBytes("UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.fillInStackTrace());
            }
            return body;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("token", userToken);
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        protected Response parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            try {
                Log.i(TAG, "Mahdi: HomeFragment: getCar: res 1 " + response.data);
                String jsonString = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | JSONException e) {
                return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
            }
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

}

But when I run my app I got this error from Volley `com.android.volley.TimeoutError`, and some image from postman for more information:

Authorization tab:

[image]

Body tab:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what i would do firstly here is test the Json the Volley request is generating `jsonObject.toString();` then personally for my Volley requests my body requests look like the following

```
  @Override
    public byte[] getBody()
    {
        byte[] body;
        body = mRequestBody.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        return body;
    }
```